# have a question about how to display json data inside a card

Tags: javascript, html, json

Im trying to display event_image, title and page into individual cards. I have displayed all the text I need from the json data file, but Im not sure how to display the json data into individual cards with the "event_image" picture and "title" and "page" . not really sure how to start.

My events object:

```
const events = [
  {
    id: 346659,
    language: {
      is: {
        title:
          '(In)visible | Ung Nordisk Musik Reykjavík 2022 | Gallery Svigrúm',
        text: '15. ágúst 18:00 - 20. ágúst 18:00\nGallerí KANNSKI, Gallerí Svigrúm and STAK\n\nFrítt inn!\n\nVerkin á sýningunni (In)visible eru eftir leiðbeinendur UNM gestavinnustofudvalarinnar sem fór fram í Reykjavík í mars síðastliðinn: Gunnhildur Hauksdóttir og Tine Surel Lange, ásamt þátttakandi listamanni í UNM gestavinnistofunni Ondi Madete - en öll verkin sameina hið sjáanlega og hið ósýnilega á einn eða annan hátt.\n\nFive Drawings eftir Gunnhildi Hauksdóttur\nhow do you feel? eftir Ondi Madete\nPortrait of Mrs Alving eftir Tine Surel Lange\n\nSýningin er opin frá 14 til 18 16.-19. ágúst og frá 10 til 18 á Menningarnótt, 20. ágúst, í Gallerý KANNSKI á Lindargötu 66, Gallerý Svigrúm á Hverfisgötu 37 og STAK á Hverfisgötu 32.\n\nGrafísk hönnun: Hrefna Sigurðardóttir\nLjósmynd: Hildur Elísa Jónsdóttir',
        place: 'Gallery Svigrúm',
        tags: [
          'Gallerý Kannski',
          'STAK',
          'Gallery Svigrúm',
          'menningarnott.is',
          'Ung Nordisk Musik',
          'Ung Nordisk Musik Reykjavík 2022',
          'Hátíðir',
          'Sýningar',
          'www.borginokkar.is',
          'visitreykjavik.is',
          'Sjónlistir',
          'Myndlist',
          'Tónlist',
        ],
      },
      en: {
        title: '(In)visible | Ung Nordisk Musik Reykjavík 2022',
        text: '15. ágúst 18:00 - 20. ágúst 18:00\nReykjavík, Iceland\nGallerí KANNSKI, Gallerí Svigrúm and STAK\n\nFree entry!\n\nThe works that make (In)visible are by UNM residency mentors Gunnhildur Hauksdóttir and Tine Surel Lange, and UNM resident Ondi Madete - but all the pieces combine the visible and the invisible in one way or another.\n\nFive Drawings by Gunnhildur Hauksdóttir\nhow do you feel? by Ondi Madete\nPortrait of Mrs Alving by Tine Surel Lange\n\nThe exhibition will be open 14-18 on August 16-19 and from 10-18 on August 20 in Gallerý KANNSKI on Lindargata 66, Gallerý Svigrúm on Hverfisgata 37 and STAK on Hverfisgata 32.\n\nMore events and concerts at Ung Nordisk Musik Reykjavík 2022: co·structing > design by Hrefna Sigurðardóttir\nPhoto by Hildur Elísa Jónsdóttir',
        place: 'Gallery Svigrúm',
        tags: [
          'Gallerý Kannski',
          'STAK',
          'Gallery Svigrúm',
          'menningarnott.is',
          'Ung Nordisk Musik',
          'Ung Nordisk Musik Reykjavík 2022',
          'Hátíðir',
          'Sýningar',
          'www.borginokkar.is',
          'visitreykjavik.is',
          'Sjónlistir',
          'Myndlist',
          'Tónlist',
        ],
      },
    },
    event_image:
      '/media/images/unm2022_eventbanners_invisible_dN6XT5p.format-jpeg.jpg',
    thumbnail_image:
      '/media/images/unm2022_eventbann.2e16d0ba.fill-255x255-c100.format-jpeg_H3dmbdW.jpg',
    accepted: true,
    active: true,
    end: '2022-08-20T23:59',
    event: true,
    image: {
      time: 1660069585,
      path: '',
      small:
        '/media/images/unm2022_eventbann.2e16d0ba.fill-160x120-c100.format-jpeg_65SoFVD.jpg',
      medium:
        '/media/images/unm2022_eventbann.2e16d0ba.fill-320x240-c100.format-jpeg_OIHsUox.jpg',
      large:
        '/media/images/unm2022_eventbann.2e16d0ba.fill-640x480-c100.format-jpeg_eJOCnL0.jpg',
      xlarge:
        '/media/images/unm2022_eventban.2e16d0ba.fill-1200x760-c100.format-jpeg_R4p89Bk.jpg',
      original:
        '/media/images/unm2022_eventbanners_invisible_dN6X.original.format-jpeg.jpg',
      image_id: 'img_10601',
    },
    legacy: false,
    formatted_address: 'Hverfisgata 37, 101 Reykjavík',
    city: 'Reykjavík',
    location: [64.1463515465167, -21.9295881721258],
    occurrence: 'multiple',
    owner: 2340,
    postal: '101',
    start: '2022-08-20T00:00',
    street: 'Hverfisgata 32',
    template: false,
    dates: [],
    tags: [
      'Gallerý Kannski',
      'STAK',
      'Gallery Svigrúm',
      'menningarnott.is',
      'Ung Nordisk Musik',
      'Ung Nordisk Musik Reykjavík 2022',
      'Hátíðir',
      'Sýningar',
      'www.borginokkar.is',
      'visitreykjavik.is',
      'Sjónlistir',
      'Myndlist',
      'Tónlist',
    ],
    media: {
      website: 'ungnordiskmusik.is',
      facebook: '',
      tickets: null,
    },
    event_id: '9bdbe57c-b8c2-4255-af29-c5a33dab49bd',
    _id: '9335dcf9-2eae-48bb-a918-a902deff017d',
    linked_service: null,
  },
  {
    id: 327609,
    language: {
      is: {
        title: 'Reykjavíkurmaraþon Íslandsbanka',
        text: 'Reykjavíkurmaraþon Íslandsbanka fer fram í 37 sinn þann 20. ágúst 2022. Í Reykjavíkurmarþoninu er hægt að velja fjórar vegalengdir, maraþon, hálfmaraþon, 10 km og Skemmtiskokk sem er um 3 km fyrir allan aldur.',
        place: 'lækjargata',
        tags: [
          'visitreykjavik.is',
          'Fjölskyldan',
          'www.borginokkar.is',
          'Hátíðir',
          'Börn',
          'menningarnott.is',
        ],
      },
      en: {
        title: 'Islandsbanki Reykjavik Marathon',
        text: 'Islandsbanki Reykjavik marathon is on August 20th for the 37th time. There are four distances available, marathon, halfmarathon, 10 k and 3 k Fun Run, which is for all ages.',
        place: 'Lækjargata',
        tags: [
          'visitreykjavik.is',
          'Fjölskyldan',
          'www.borginokkar.is',
          'Hátíðir',
          'Börn',
          'menningarnott.is',
        ],
      },
    },
    event_image: '/media/images/14822665739_3b823bfc39_c.format-jpeg.jpg',
    thumbnail_image:
      '/media/images/14822665739_3b823.2e16d0ba.fill-255x255-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
    accepted: true,
    active: true,
    end: '2022-08-20T17:00',
    event: true,
    image: {
      time: 1659965899,
      path: '',
      small:
        '/media/images/14822665739_3b823.2e16d0ba.fill-160x120-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      medium:
        '/media/images/14822665739_3b823.2e16d0ba.fill-320x240-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      large:
        '/media/images/14822665739_3b823.2e16d0ba.fill-640x480-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      xlarge:
        '/media/images/14822665739_3b82.2e16d0ba.fill-1200x760-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      original:
        '/media/images/14822665739_3b823bfc39_c.original.format-jpeg.jpg',
      image_id: 'img_10585',
    },
    legacy: false,
    formatted_address: 'Lækjargata 12, 101 Reykjavík',
    city: 'Reykjavík',
    location: [64.1460697014646, -21.9388311630062],
    occurrence: 'single',
    owner: 1986,
    postal: '101',
    start: '2022-08-20T08:40',
    street: 'Lækjargata 12',
    template: false,
    dates: [],
    tags: [
      'visitreykjavik.is',
      'Fjölskyldan',
      'www.borginokkar.is',
      'Hátíðir',
      'Börn',
      'menningarnott.is',
    ],
    media: {
      website: 'https://www.rmi.is/',
      facebook: 'https://www.facebook.com/Reykjavikurmarathon',
      tickets:
        'https://www.corsa.is/is/register/37?fbclid=IwAR2WxLUpyUTv1Mu7jyZq-YY90wpApuJjg35kfRG3wBjOz7xWMT5L6mK19uY',
    },
    event_id: 'd51fbe3b-e139-4186-b707-00c81e34ca86',
    _id: 'e589ff8c-4518-48b9-8d73-2b9906d78cf9',
    linked_service: null,
  },
  {
    id: 328345,
    language: {
      is: {
        title: 'Smiðja: Klippivíðátta',
        text: 'Gestir geta sest niður, klippt og límt og tekið þátt í að skapa víðáttumynd í anda Errós. Smiðjan er staðsett á 2. hæð í Hafnarhúsi, á bryggjunni.\n\nÓkeypis aðgangur.',
        place: 'Listasafn Reykjavíkur Hafnarhús',
        tags: [
          'menningarnott.is',
          'Börn',
          'Sýningar',
          'www.borginokkar.is',
          'Fjölskyldan',
          'visitreykjavik.is',
          'Sjónlistir',
          'Myndlist',
        ],
      },
      en: {
        title: 'Workshop: Collage scape',
        text: 'Guests can sit down, cut and glue and create a scape in the spirit of Erró.The workshop is located on the 1st floor of Hafnarhús.\n\nFree entry.',
        place: 'Reykjavík Art Museum Hafnarhús',
        tags: [
          'menningarnott.is',
          'Börn',
          'Sýningar',
          'www.borginokkar.is',
          'Fjölskyldan',
          'visitreykjavik.is',
          'Sjónlistir',
          'Myndlist',
        ],
      },
    },
    event_image:
      '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider__Naeturriddari-1985_Large.format-jpeg.jpg',
    thumbnail_image:
      '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider_.2e16d0ba.fill-255x255-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
    accepted: true,
    active: true,
    end: '2022-08-20T18:00',
    event: true,
    image: {
      time: 1660233546,
      path: '',
      small:
        '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider_.2e16d0ba.fill-160x120-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      medium:
        '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider_.2e16d0ba.fill-320x240-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      large:
        '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider_.2e16d0ba.fill-640x480-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      xlarge:
        '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider.2e16d0ba.fill-1200x760-c100.format-jpeg.jpg',
      original:
        '/media/images/Erro-Ghost_Rider__Naeturriddari-198.original.format-jpeg.jpg',
      image_id: 'img_10634',
    },
    legacy: false,
    formatted_address: 'Tryggvagata 17, 101 Reykjavík',
    city: 'Reykjavík',
    location: [64.1490646175321, -21.9404658877717],
    occurrence: 'single',
    owner: 4,
    postal: '101',
    start: '2022-08-20T10:00',
    street: 'Tryggvagata 17',
    template: false,
    dates: [],
    tags: [
      'menningarnott.is',
      'Börn',
      'Sýningar',
      'www.borginokkar.is',
      'Fjölskyldan',
      'visitreykjavik.is',
      'Sjónlistir',
      'Myndlist',
    ],
    media: {
      website:
        'https://listasafnreykjavikur.is/vi%C3%B0burdir/listasafn-reykjavikur-menningarnott',
      facebook: 'https://www.facebook.com/events/332202605704059',
      tickets: null,
    },
    event_id: '98cd1285-e627-4cc5-98f0-c49c2bea460b',
    _id: '14171dc9-8fdc-453d-906c-5bc02e07354d',
    linked_service: null,
  },
];
```

My code:

```
let output = '<ul>';

events.forEach((event) => {
  output += `<li> title: ${event.language.is.title} - place: ${event.language.is.place} </li> `;
});

output += '</ul> <hr>';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += output;
```

not really sure how to start

Comment: is this a public API? If so could you share it to test and give a more effective answer?

Comment: yes here is the api: https://hvirfill.reykjavik.is/find?search=&all=menningarnott.is&range=2022-08-20%2C2022-08-20&limit=30&offset=0&sort=start&lang=is

Comment: link to code if that helps: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lwyztk?file=index.js,index.html,style.css

Comment: much appreciated, will try to give you an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on my understanding of your code, you have already got a decent starting point. However dumping everything into a list will not achieve your need for individual "cards" without some rigorous styling. To maintain HTML semantics, use a `<h1>–<h6>` element for the title, the `<article>` element for the card itself, and the `<dl>` `<dt>` `<dd>` elements for your information in each "card".

What the `event_image` property of each event provides is the URL path to where the image is stored on [hvirfill.reykjavik.is](https://hvirfill.reykjavik.is/#/)'s server. All you need to do in your code is add an `<img>` element with the `src` attribute as the base URL of the site appended with the path provided by the `event_image` property.

Also, consider moving the opening and closing parts of your `output` string variable within the assignment itself for cleaner code and better readability.

Additionally, avoid using the `.forEach()` Array method on its own as it should really be used at the end of a chain of other Array methods (like `.filter().map().forEach()`). Instead use the more readable and more functional `for...of` statement.

All of my comments above are demonstrated in the snippet below:

```
let outputData = '';

for (let event of events) {
  outputData += `<article><h2>${event.language.is.title}</h2><dl><dt>place:</dt><dd>${event.language.is.place}</dd></dl><img width='200px' src='https://hvirfill.reykjavik.is${event.event_image}'></article>`;
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += `${outputData}`;
```

To better achieve the "card" effect, use styling:

```
article {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Of course, you can style all this however you want but always try to do this with CSS. For example, don't use a `<hr>` element just for the line it provides visually. You should generally choose all your HTML elements semantically, as per standards. You can read more about each of the elements and when you should use them on [MDN's HTML element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element).

As you were nice enough to provide a Stackblitz example, I will do the same [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jyllw8?file=index.js).

Hope this helps.